# AWS SNS equivalent in GCP stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-sns

So we spent almost 6 months in moving our current app stack from AWS to GCP and now we got stuck at the AWS-SNS part.

Apparently there seems to be no service in GCP stack that can simply provide a drop in replacement for SNS or did I miss something?

Right now everything is running perfectly fine on GCP and every call to SNS in the app is still using the old AWS account.

SNS is being used primarily to notify events occurring in the app like "batch completed successfully" or "export failed with xyz error".

What are our options here?

Comment: I was on that path a couple months ago, as other people already suggested Cloud Pub/Sub is the most similar option here, take a look at this project where I switch from AWS queus to GCP. https://github.com/oscarnevarezleal/ecommerce-crawler

Answer (score 5):

The closest SNS replacement in GCP is probably [Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/docs/compare/aws/application-services), which provides a similar publish-subscribe messaging pattern.

[This document](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview) shows how the topics and subscriptions work.

Comment: Howdy Tom ... by any chance did you confuse AWS SNS with AWS SQS?  I did at first.

Comment: No, it wasn't clear to me if the OP is interested in the publish-subscribe functionality of SNS or the SMS notification part of SNS. Cloud Pub/Sub satisfies the publish-subscribe part, but if the OP is interested in sending SMS messages, a custom built solution is needed.

Answer (score 1):

At present, GCP does not have a native / proprietary email or text message service.  Instead, the recommendation is to use sendgrid for emails and twilio for messages.  See the following articles that describe the usage of these services:

- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/sms/twilio
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sendgrid

Comment: This is correct, GCP does not have SMS functionality yet. You can review Firebase Cloud Messaging [https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging] which covers a few of the other gaps in SNS.

Comment: @jl1990 SNS supports SMS https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-mobile-phone-number-as-subscriber.html

Answer (score 0):

GCP has recently launched a service which allows you to send SMS ([session based](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/ccai-platform/docs/SMS#UUID-deaac933-cb96-01de-a409-b74a4cafb35d) or [session less](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/ccai-platform/docs/SMS#UUID-7277df40-2eed-42c3-4ec6-3bf1dda645a1))
But, for pricing and activation, you have to contact their support team.

These APIs are part of a broader product they launched ([Cloud Contact Center](https://cloud.google.com/contact-center/ccai-platform/docs/SMS#UUID-18f05947-8e14-e06e-5780-071a421b0694) .

Hope that helps!